# jquery its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website,two days ago is everyting was good. Today I checked,and the javascripts doesn't work. The browser give me this:

[image]

The is my code:

```
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
In a html code I had opened html comment ,and this made me a problem. Thank you for everybody!

Comment: We can't help you if all you're going to say is it doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinB There is an error in the image he linked.

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong.

Comment: if you paste this url in your browser does it come up?  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js

Comment: Go ahead and add screenshots of what you're seeing with it not working and also mention what you expect to happen if it does work :)

Comment: In other words, this problem (a typo) was solved in a way that is not useful to future visitors and therefore should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're loading resources using both `https` and `http`. Try loading them with `//` instead so they simply match the protocol used to load the page (either `http` or `https`, but they'll be consistent).

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now no error,but still not working. :)

Comment: Perhaps you could mark this as the solution for this question since this fixes the error and might help others.